# Cross validation vs validation set

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I am studying for the Statistical learning exam and my professor has put me in doubt as to when it is preferable to use cross-validation and when the validation set: he said that with less than 2000 observations it is better to use cross-validation, with more than 2000 observations it is better to use the validation set. Yet I think it is more the other way round, also because of the more stable estimates generated by the cross-validation method. 
Can anyone help me?
 Thanks

Comment: I don't like this rule - but anyway the logic goes along these lines: With large data, you can usually spare 20% and still have enough training rows. The smaller the data, the more it hurts to reduce it by 20%.

Comment: I use cross validation on around 100 observations samples too.